# IReport - Making Detail Bands Print Separately

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on a report where I use two detail bands (detail 1 and detail 2).
I have one field in detail 1 and another field in detail 2. Right now they print like:

Field one

Field two

Field one

Field two

Is there a way where I can print like this:

Field one

Field one

Field two

Field two

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't separate the data from one record. In your case I would proceed like this :

Have your data duplicated : for example if you had

> object1, object2, object3

Have it like :

> object1, object2, object3, object1, object2, object3

Add a boolean that is true for first set, and false for the second set.

```
class myClass {
    Object field1;
    Object field2;
    boolean useField1;
}
```

> object1 - true, object2 - true, object3 - true, object1 - false, object2 - false, object3 - false

In your report : if boolean is `true` display field 1, otherwise display field 2.

```
o.useField1 ? o.field1 : o.field2
```